# Is it possible to do arithmetic in a template conditional?

Tags: django

Basically I'd like to do this but the syntax is not valid.

```
            {% if index in widget.row_starts %}
                <div class="row">
            {% elif index+1 in widget.row_starts %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

I tried using index|add:1 but I *think* that is actually incrementing the value permanently...

Comment: What is index ? Are you in for loop ?

Comment: Yes, I'm in a for loop. It's a number.